# How does closures work in Javascript when we return a function?

Tags: javascript

Suppose I have two functions test1 and test2!

```
test1 = function(name){
    console.log('Hi, ', name);
};

test2 = function(name) {
    var text = 'Hello ' + name;
    var say = function() { console.log(text); }
    return say;
}
```

Now I call the function and save them to vars,

```
var t1 = test1('John');
var t2 = test2('John');
```

What is exactly happening here?

Comment: `test1` will execute the function and print out '`Hi John` and `return undefined`. `t1` will be `undefined`. `test2` will return a new `function` with a closure over `text` and assign it to `t2`. `t2` is now a new `function`. You will need to execute it in order to get any output, which you haven't done yet

Comment: i think you can call say like `t2();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Lets understand this**:

In below code you are defining a function called `test1` which will print `Hi,  John` if you use test1('John').

```
test1 = function(name){
    console.log('Hi, ', name);
};
```

Now lets understand below code, below you are defining a function called `test2` which:

```
test2 = function(name) {
    var text = 'Hello ' + name;
    var say = function() { console.log(text); }
    return say;
}
```

- `var text = 'Hello ' + name;` //define a variable called `text`
- `var say = function() { console.log(text); }`  //defininga a function called `say` which will log the data in variable `text` in the console.
- Then you are returning `say` function.

**OUTPUT:**
Input: => `var t1 = test1('John');`
Output: => `Hi,  John` //It's quite straight forward.

Input: => `var t2 = test2('John');`
Output: => `undefined` //Here you are re-assigning function returned from `test2` which was `say` to `t2`. Hence if you now type `t2` then you wil get `function () { console.log(text); }` as output which is similar to `say`.

I hope you understood, sorry for poor english.

Answer (score 2):

Your function `test1` returns void, since there is no `return` statement
This function prints `Hi John` to the console

Your function `test2` returns the function `say()` to the console and stores it in `t2`. This makes `t2` a function. If you pay attention to the syntax in `test2` that's one of the two standard ways of defining a function in javascript. if you call

`t2();`
you will get the similar output to `test1('John');`:

`Hello John`

Comment: Good and complete answer! One little mistake I found: t2() prints "Hello John", while test1('John') prints "Hi, John". But that is certainly not important for the technical understanding.

Answer (score 1):

On calling, test2 returns 'say' which is a pointer to a function, not the value. That is why it will not output anything.
To call function 'say' you need to do `test2('john')()`.
In the second pair of parenthesis, we pass in the arguments to the function inside.

Answer (score 1):

your first function executes a code and don`t return any thing then t1 will be undefined. but second function returns a function then t2 contains a function that never called so it will not log to console